# Comparing values of two columns for a large number of rows in a data set and forming a new column with new values in R

Tags: r

I have a data set like this:

```
test=

 subject  stim        IFNG      n
   <chr>    <chr>       <chr> <int>
 1 DL (HC2) (1) no stim 0        96
 2 DL (HC2) (2) 1100-2  0        54
 3 DL (HC2) (2) 1100-2  1        42
 4 DL (HC2) (3) BSV18   0        84
 5 DL (HC2) (3) BSV18   1        12
 6 HAT-001  (1) no stim 0        96
 7 HAT-001  (2) 1100-2  0        65
 8 HAT-001  (2) 1100-2  1        31
 9 HAT-001  (3) BSV18   0        79
10 HAT-001  (3) BSV18   1        17
```

For the same '`subject`' and '`stim`' value, I want to get the '`n`' values for when `INFG= 0` and `1` and then find the proportion for which `IFNG=1`.

For example, for row 2 and 3 the subject and stim values are the same (`DL(HC2)` and `(2) 1100-2 respectively`). For row 2 `IFNG == 0` and for row 3 `IFNG == 1`. I want to get the n values for `IFNG == 0` and `IFNG == 1` which are 54 and 42 respectively. Then I want to make a new column which gives the new n value, `42/(54+42)=42.78`.
 If the '`subject`' and '`stim`' does not match, then the new n value=`n`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr` package and specifically the `group_by` function:

```
test %>%
group_by(subject, stim) %>%
mutate(sum.col = sum(n),
       prop = n/sum.col * 100) %>%
```

Comment: Did my solution help?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help.